# Formatting python dictionaries with break lines

Tags: python, dictionary, line, break

I have this dictionary;

```
results = {'name': sectionAddr.name,
               'count': sampleCount,
               'finish_count': len(finished),
               'inside4_count': inside4Count,
               'inside10_count': inside10Count,
               'finish_rate': 100 * len(finished) / sampleCount,
               'inside4_rate': 100 * inside4Count / sampleCount,
               'inside10_rate': 100 * inside10Count / sampleCount,
               'mean_error': meanError,
               'stddev_error': stddevError,
               'samples': sampleResults}
    results['error'] = getError(results
```

But I need do display it; and if i do that by the formatting to str, it looks like a string, i.e. a line. How i should to break line after the each variable?

Something like that:

```
results = {'name': sectionAddr.name + '\n', 
'finish_count': len(finished), ...
```

doesn't work,

how I can break lines?

Comment: This is a dictionary, not a set. I'm assuming you don't want a set at any point and it's just a mistake?

Answer (score 3):

A pretty print would probably meet your needs;

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(result)
```

If you don't feel like using pretty print;

```
result = {'a': '1',
          'b': '2',
          'c': '3'}

print('\n'.join(('\t'.join(item) for item in result.items())))
```

Outputs;

```
a   1
c   3
b   2
```

Comment: Exatly that I need, but there is an error: 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict'

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pprint.pformat` to get a nicely formatted string:

```
import pprint

results = {'name': "sectionAddr.name",
               'count': "sampleCount",
               'finish_count': "len(finished)",
               'inside4_count': "inside4Count",
               'inside10_count': "inside10Count",
               'samples': "sampleResults"}

s = pprint.pformat(results)

print(s)
```

Output:

```
{'count': 'sampleCount',
 'finish_count': 'len(finished)',
 'inside10_count': 'inside10Count',
 'inside4_count': 'inside4Count',
 'name': 'sectionAddr.name',
 'samples': 'sampleResults'}
```

Or, if you do not need it as a string but want to print to the console directly, you can use `pprint.pprint`:

```
pprint.pprint(results)
```

Note that a dictionary has no fixed order, so the keys in the formatted string might be in different order.

Both `pformat` and `pprint` accept additional parameters, so you can modify the result: [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html)

Comment: thanks, but if i want to write it into a file? it will be the line, how add the '\n'?

Comment: @E.Trofimov did you try to write the ``pformat`` formatted string to a file?

Comment: there is an html file

Answer (score 0):

Python Pretty Printer Documentation

```
>>> import pprint
>>> tup = ('spam', ('eggs', ('lumberjack', ('knights', ('ni', ('dead',
... ('parrot', ('fresh fruit',))))))))
>>> stuff = ['a' * 10, tup, ['a' * 30, 'b' * 30], ['c' * 20, 'd' * 20]]
>>> pprint.pprint(stuff)
['aaaaaaaaaa',
 ('spam',
  ('eggs',
   ('lumberjack',
    ('knights', ('ni', ('dead', ('parrot', ('fresh fruit',)))))))),
 ['aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'],
 ['cccccccccccccccccccc', 'dddddddddddddddddddd']]
```

Your use-case:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(results)
```